# ros hello - problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i was doing the beginner tutorial for accomodating a basic C++ 'Hello World' programme (helloROS.cpp) into ROS nodes, and i was following the steps to create a package. In step 2# "rospack find hello" it says "rospack not found" and I dont understand why... all the folders were created and are in the package hello in my documents.
Please help as soon as possible. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65047/ros-hello---problem.../) by [Sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5142/sigma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-13**:
helloROS.cpp is not in the standard tutorials.  Can you provide a link to the tutorial you are following?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-06-13**:
@tfoote Seems I should take responsibility, I would think that this is the tutorial in reference, http://mobotica.blogspot.in/2011/12/hello-ros.html and I guess that this is a ROS_PATH issue, the package is probably not visible !

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-06-13**:
@tfoote I have made some modifications, I named it 'for a rookie' but never explained ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ! .... :-( ..... should work now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's saying that rospack is not found.  Did you source the setup.bash in your active terminal?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1